# Android simple animation - 90 degree rotation around X axis

Tags: android, animation, 3d, rotation, scale

I'm rotating a view 90 degrees around the X axis.  (I.e. it looks like the view is falling forward out of the screen towards the user).

1. I extend Animation, and inside applyTransformation(), I do

   ```
   protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
   final float fromDegrees = mFromDegrees;
   float degrees = fromDegrees + ((mToDegrees - fromDegrees) * interpolatedTime);

   final float centerX = mCenterX;
   final float centerY = mCenterY;
   final Camera camera = mCamera;

   final Matrix matrix = t.getMatrix();

   camera.save();
   camera.rotateX(degrees);
   camera.getMatrix(matrix);
   camera.restore();

   matrix.preTranslate(-centerX, -centerY);

   matrix.setScale(0.75f, 0.75f);  // doesn't do anything

   matrix.postTranslate(centerX, centerY);
   ```

   }

That works fine, and I get the animation I want.

I also want to reduce the size of the view a little bit when it animates.

I thought this would do it (at the place shown in the code above).

```
        matrix.setScale(0.75f, 0.75f);  // doesn't do anything
```

But that doesn't appear to have any effect.

How can I scale down the size of the view during my animation?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use matrix.preScale(x,x,x,x);